# Remove the first word in a string continuously and keep the last word [Xamarin Forms] C#

Tags: c#, string, xamarin, xamarin.forms, speech-recognition

I have a function that will take a `string` and remove its first word and always keep the last word.

The string gets returned from my function `SFSpeechRecognitionResult result`.

With my current code it works when the code runs once, the first word gets deleted from the string and only the last word is left. But when the function runs again then the newly added words just keep stacking up in the `result.BestTranscription.FormattedString` `string` and the first word does not get removed.

This is my function:

```
RecognitionTask = SpeechRecognizer.GetRecognitionTask
(
    LiveSpeechRequest, 
    (SFSpeechRecognitionResult result, NSError err) =>
    {
        if (result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.Contains(" "))
        {
            //and this is where I try to remove the first word and keep the last 
            string[] values = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.Split(' ');
            var words = values.Skip(1).ToList(); 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var word in words)
            {
                sb.Append(word + " ");
            }

            string newresult = sb.ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newresult);
        }
        else 
        {
            //if the string only has one word then I will run this normally
            thetextresult = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.ToLower();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(thetextresult);
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: It might be because you always append a space at the end of the string, therefore `.Contains(" ")` is always true? Try `String.Join(" ", words)` instead.

Comment: Why keep this as a string and not a `List<string>` for the individual words? Or maybe even a `Queue<string>` as this is how it seems to be working?

Comment: An even faster way would be `string newresult = previousresult.Substring(previousresult.IndexOf(" "));`

Comment: If I do: `if (howmanyTimesUsed == 0)
     {
      howmanyTimesUsed = howmanyTimesUsed + 1;
      thetextresult = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.ToLower();
      resultCallback(thetextresult);
     }
     else {
      string newresult = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.Substring
      (result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.IndexOf(" "));
      resultCallback(newresult);

     }` The string still keeps adding words without getting removed

Comment: noticed i get a lot of downvotes :( is it because i did not show enough code?

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez it might be because in your post a clear question with a `?` is missing, or that your problem description is not solid enough for somebody, or the people simply are trying to help you getting the peer-pressure badge ;) they usually don't comment on their downvotes unfortunately

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez Also what usually helps to understand a current situation of string manipulation is an example_input-string and an example_expected_output-string

Comment: @MongZhu Yeah! I will try to implement more "?" in my text. When it comes to the problem. The thing is that "result" does not remove the first word. so when I the function runs again all of the words are still there + new words so therefor it does not work correctly after the first "run". I am a bit unsure how I should remove the first word in the result value completely though

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez "the newly added words to the string just keeps stacking up " at which level are you looking? at `result.BestTranscription.FormattedString` ? can you post one example of what is in `result.BestTranscription.FormattedString` at three iterations? so we can see how it piles up

Comment: @MongZhu the function is a "speak-function". so when I talk the thing i say gets stored in `result.BestTranscription.FormattedString` so that means, if i say "apple" it gets written out in the log just fine and then if i 5 seconds later say "banana", then the `result.BestTranscription.FormattedString` will be a string looking like this: "apple banana". my goal is to then have the word "apple" removed and only the latest word left which in this case is "banana". and if i say a 3rd word, "pineapple" then banana should get removed etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129241/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-carlos-rodrigez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to just take the last element after splitting:

```
string last_word = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.Split(' ').Last();
```

This will give you always the last word

make sure that `result.BestTranscription.FormattedString != null` before splitting otherwise you get an exception.

May be there is also an option to clear the string of words after the processing of the first, so that you always get only the word that is recorded last. You could try to reset it at the end like this:

```
result.BestTranscription.FormattedString = "";
```

Basically your code would look something like this:

```
if (result.BestTranscription.FormattedString != null && 
    result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.Contains(" "))
{
    //and this is where I try to remove the first word and keep the last 
    string lastWord = result.BestTranscription.FormattedString.Split(' ')Last();

    string newresult = lastWord;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newresult);
}
```

Comment: @CarlosRodrigez glad I could help.